Google Script app to connect the MySQL database with Google Sheets
I want to use the Google Script app to connect the MySQL database with Google Sheets. However, on the database server I implemented a firewall with a whitelist of only certain IPs that can be accessed. Does anyone know how many google app script IPs I can add, or is there another alternative solution?

If you don't know exactly which IPs you need, then there's really no way to do whitelist firewalling.

Titles should be a summary of the question. See [ask]
